# microsoft subdomain with facebook . what it belongs to?

Tags: subdomain

I am just curious to see the url https://microsoft.facebook.com/ . what it is ?
Signup page show **Facebook at Work** Title. what it represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB Has started a new domain where employees can use facebook in office enviornment.

This could be the enviorment dedicated to Microsoft Employees.

**[Further Readings](https://www.facebook.com/help/work)**